# Typing object path in dot notation

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a string representing an object path in dot notation (ie: `"users.1.name"`). I'm getting pretty close to have a fully functional solution.
My last issue is that recursive types will fail with this error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

I'd like to solve this issue, or at least find a way to limit the recursion so that I don't get this error.

Here is my code ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=36&ssc=75&pln=36&pc=14#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgSQLZgDYB4AqAaKAaSggA9gIA7AEwGcoBrCEAewDMocA%20KAXgCgoREuSp0oAClrAATgEtKAcygAfKJQCuqAEYQZASkFQA-JwDahALoiKNegCUIAYxYzqWafKUE4lEFyMhUxwLazJbcQBBGRk4EAAZOSYsX39AoRNhNQADABIAb0IAXwA6AvgkNExcUIJNHT0uIuz0oQAuLKg8wtLyhBR0bBCrAiZWDmHLJpaMqA7CIw7KCAA3PQBufn4yMFdgKFBIKAB5bQArZ2AKxFweXlh%20qqHR5nZOHjUxt5xNrYB6P6cCDSNpbQ7QACqtD0fCg%20SMlDgqAgHU8CkUeCMcGo1BkwNoHXhswwCmBhNaUE8EAgwFRsnRmNmQipNIAclpdDIlhy9OkimZLIyMgAvORgOleDFGIr8Iq-FyUaSU2TU4Dshpck7nS7XLBQxqwgBE2Nx%20JKJOWtBKACYSiy1TyZIaoACoIBQcn4CqVbBYLA6pwuTiu-T10JkdygxpxeNoVotwJtJR9LGdrsAMuRQPGB4D0BQrOAk6hQMD9KBweg7S4QahbfiuxxODQyWhyNYHcDQCQ4ADKUDk9DYpKgAHc5Eg%208BDOCoPqZAB1MeIABi8jE9HuRPUSJRyslQrYq7sHVnC6QK7ka4Fsv%20gJ7UAAojFXB0cB2%204rgL5gHIEHIWJQ%20wrUgnHxVsIAwEAoGoakwDLGhixYWM5G0CD30HSgxwgEpPX-b1-W1INdRPRdzzXCMAHJEWRcjay2IA)):

```
type PathImpl<T, K extends keyof T> =
  K extends (string | number)
  ? T[K] extends Record<string, any>
    ? T[K] extends ArrayLike<any>
      ? K | `${K}.${PathImpl<T[K], number>}`
      : K | `${K}.${PathImpl<T[K], keyof T[K]>}`
    : K
  : never;

export type ObjectPath<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T> | keyof T;


// Test:

type User = {
  name: string,
  address: {
    lines: {
      street: string,
      streetNumber: number
    }[],
    zip: string,
  }
};

const streetNumber: ObjectPath<User> = "address.lines.2.streetNumber" // ✅
const foo: ObjectPath<User> = "address.lines.2.foo" // ❌ rejects invalid path as expected


// Recursive type (TS is fine with it)
type UserWithFriends = {
  name: string,
  friends: UserWithFriends[]
}

// TS Error: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
const f: ObjectPath<UserWithFriends> = 'name'
```

(this code was inspired by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/diegohaz/status/1309489079378219009?lang=en))

Comment: I use [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6XzEm) which covers more cases and *doesn't* freak out.

Comment: Hm, actually, with recursive types, I don't think you can do this. You would need a generic helper function to do the inference. However, if you are planning to use this as a type of a parameter in a function, it's already doable.

Comment: You could add a recursion limit: https://tsplay.dev/w8xRPw

Comment: I'm cleaning it up a bit, making it more explicit: https://tsplay.dev/wRXKnm

Comment: Oh no! I was happy with my implementation but TS 4.9 is breaking it. Do you guys by chance have an idea of how to fix it @TobiasS. ? https://tsplay.dev/NdrGyW

Comment: @TomEsterez - very interesting. This seems like a bug. Might be worth opening an issue. To fix it: It should be enough to intersect the `number` like this -> `number & keyof T[K]`. Maybe this breaks some other stuff but you should try it.

Comment: Your suggested fix does work for me  I did open an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51540 Thanks @TobiasS. , you rock 